# Lawvere category of categories for foundations

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Does anybody know where I can find this article 
"Lawvere, F. W., 1966, “The Category of Categories as a Foundation for Mathematics”?

I've looked long for the web without any luck, I'll be grateful to anyone who can find it.

Comment: I haven't seen online editions of any of the articles in the La Jolla proceedings (1966 Proc. Conf. Categorical Algebra (La Jolla, Calif., 1965)) so far. So you should probably go to the library and locate them there. Any good math library should have it. For what it's worth the MathSciNet review of Lawvere's article is [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=207517).

Comment: yes I also looked for it unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lawvere work on CAT cannot be found online, but I found this page in nlab very interesting: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fully+formal+ETCS . Altough the title only mentions ETCS, it really formalizes CAT (the quasicategory of categories)

Comment: I know this is many years later, but it doesn't formalize CAT as intended by Lawvere. For one, there is no notion of functor or natural transformation. It's true that a functor is a morphism between models, but this means that we need something outside of category theory to obtain this.